# Mac Pro: UI hangs, all background processes fine

Tags: performance

I have a Mac Pro that has an issue I haven't seen with any of my other Macs. Occasionally, once a week or so, the UI will hang and beachball while the rest of the machine will keep running. Skype calls continue, music keeps playing. I can ssh in and use the terminal. Everything works except the UI is completely frozen. I have to power cycle. I'm running the latest macOS, but previous versions did it all well.

Do you I diagnose the root cause of the issue.

Comment: Which Mac Pro? Is it the old tower or the new cylinder? What model number?

Comment: It is the first of the trash can models.

Comment: Has this problem been happening for a while? Is it new with Sierra? When did it start? Right after you upgraded?

Comment: It's been happening for a while, since before I upgraded.

Comment: Does the mouse pointer still move or is that frozen as well? You could look at the process list in the terminal and see if anything is frozen.

Comment: The mouse cursor still moves.